# Best practice for loading javascript code for multiple pages and code specific for just one page

Tags: javascript

I know that there are many similar questions about how to load javascript files but this one is more about what to do with page specific files.

So, here is the question:

I have a couple of javascript files with different functionalities. Some of them are used on many pages and some just on one specific page.

From your practice, is it better to:

1. Load scripts for many pages on all pages and page specific scripts only on the specific pages.
   (PROBLEM: many requests for js and css files)
2. Load just one big javascript file (that contains all those scripts including scripts for many and specific pages) on all pages.
   (PROBLEM: code needed only for one page will be present on all pages)

Comment: 2. Is less of a problem than you might think - after downloading it the first time, the browser will keep the file cached and not make the request on subsequent pages.

Comment: Having one single big file is not a good practice. It's not only about loading the page faster but also about doing it in a clean way.

Answer (score 0):

You should use minification and bundling. That way you make just one request and you get all the .JS files you need. You can create a different bundle for each page if you want.

You can read more about bundling here: http://vswebessentials.com/features/bundling